# Using SQL Order statement to show last 60 days on record

Tags: sql, aspdotnetstorefront

Have a Stored Procedure with a SQL db that returns all values of products. At the end of the stored proc the order is shown as

```
ORDER BY pf.rownum
```

I have tried to include this line within the stored procedure to show the last 60 days of products

```
where
CreatedOn >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 60,0)
```

But I think that the products created on date are outside of the date scope. Is there a way of including the date selection within the ORDER BY line and removing this CreatedOn value?

This is within AspDotNetStoreFront

Thanks!

Comment: So basically what do you want your query to return? You could do ORDER BY CreatedON Desc, pf.rownum so that the newest are on top.

Comment: Try `CreatedOn >= dateadd(DD, -60, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(), 101))`.

Comment: WHERE CreatedOn>GETDATE()-60 is the shorthand I normally use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how to order by two columns?
If yes then code below should do it.

```
ORDER BY pf.rownum ASC, pf.CreatedOn DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your syntax is wrong in the where clause. I am not sure why you are using `datediff(day, 0, GetDate())`. Take that out and instead use `dateadd(dd, -60, cast(Getdate() as date))`. The only thing that order by does is tell sql how to sort the results. The order by should not affect what data is or isn't being returned.

Depending on what data type CreatedOn is stored as, you may need to do

```
cast(CreatedOn as date) >= dateadd(dd, -60, cast(Getdate() as date))
```

If CreatedOn is a datetime and you don't do this, the time will affect if the data is included in the results or not.